# Why does float in the parent container alter an img's size?

Tags: html, css

I have a container and a image inside it. When the parent is given `float`, there is a height mismatch in the child. When both are given `float` it matches. Why?

```
 <div class="parent"><img src="images/trest.png" class="image"></img></div>
```

**Mismatches when:**

```
.parent{
float:left;
}
.image{}
```

**Perfect when:**

```
.parent{
    float:left;
    }
    .image{
    float:left;
    }
```

[image]

Comment: Works for me https://jsbin.com/galoso/edit?html,output

Comment: Do you maybe have a whitespace " " between `<img/>` and the closing `</div>`? Also: there is no closing tag for `</img>`.

Comment: It's not causing the issue but `</img>` is invalid markup. `<img>` should be a self-closing tag

Comment: It is because <img> is a replaced element which has default vertical-align:baseline and baseline aligned elements reserve space for text descenders - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, specifying an element with `float` will [in most cases](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float) make it into a `block` element.

Image elements by default are known to have the issue of unwanted white space underneath when placed in a block level container. The solution typically has been to set the image element's display to `block`.

From [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/float):

> As float implies the use of the block layout, it modifies the computed value of the display values in some cases:

Comparison between `float` and `display: block` (in essence, the results are the same):

```css
.parent {
  float: left;
  border: 2px solid red;
}
.image {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
.image2 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  display: block;
}
.image3 {
  border: 2px solid blue;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="image"/></div>
<div class="parent"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="image2"/></div>
<div class="parent"><img src="https://placehold.it/100x100" class="image3"/></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

**andyb** said in a comment on the question:

> It is because <img> is a replaced element which has default vertical-align:baseline and baseline aligned elements reserve space for text descenders - see [stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/…](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5804256/image-inside-div-has-extra-space-below-the-image) – andyb

Because of this, another way to fix this is to set the `vertical-align` property to *bottom* instead of *baseline*.

From [timolawl's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37324642/17300), if you adjust the style of the first image to be:

```
.image {
    border: 2px solid blue;
    vertical-align: bottom;    /* added this */
}
```

then it will look the same as the other two, whish use `display:block` and `float` (respectively) to get the desired layout.